# constructing a maze

Tags: java, events, awt, frame, paint

At first I thought It was easy but when I started doing it I don't know how to continue anymore. My idea was to use panels, then draw thick lines, but then what's the proper way to draw the walls and make my character not move beyond those walls? I just can't imagine how I can possibly do that. Here's a sketch of a maze to illustrate How I will be doing it:

[image]

I just started with a `Frame` and still trying to grasp the idea of doing it.

Comment: You want to create random mazes or one fixed maze? Do you already have a form of collision detection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need a data-structure that represents your maze.  Then you can worry about drawing it.

I would suggest a class like this:

```
class Maze {
    public enum Tile { Start, End, Empty, Blocked };
    private final Tile[] cells;
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    public Maze(int width, int height) {
         this.width = width;
         this.height = height;
         this.cells = new Tile[width * height];
         Arrays.fill(this.cells, Tile.Empty);
    }

    public int height() {
        return height;
    }

    public int width() {
        return width;
    }

    public Tile get(int x, int y) {
        return cells[index(x, y)];
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, Tile tile) {
         Cells[index(x, y)] = tile;
    }

    private int index(int x, int y) {
        return y * width + x;
    }
}
```

Then I would draw this maze with blocks (squares), rather than lines.  A dark block for blocked tiles, and a clear one for empty tiles.

To paint, do something like this.

```
public void paintTheMaze(graphics g) {
    final int tileWidth = 32;
    final int tileHeight = 32;
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int x = 0; x < maze.width(); ++x) {
        for (int y = 0;  y < maze.height(); ++y) {
            if (maze.get(x, y).equals(Tile.Blocked)) (
                 g.fillRect(x*tileWidth, y*tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
            }
        }
    )

}
```

Comment: But then how about the `no crossing beyond this wall`?

Comment: Nope I am not, I will be controlling my character using `KeyListeners`

Comment: Then you need another class to store where your character is in the maze (his x and y coordinate) and when they press (say left) check if the cell to their left (x-1, y) is not Tile.Blocked by using the maze.get() method.